# Aligning html inputs on same line

Tags: html, css, input, alignment

Can somebody give a simple solution as to how to align form inputs on the same line,
for example, many times when I am building a form I can get them to align on top of each other and it looks sound, but if i put two inputs like a textarea/text next to another text or a button, I get vertical alignment differences. Is there a way to fix this without fiddling with the margins and padding?

ex:

```
<style type='text/css'>
  form{
    display:inline;
  }
  textarea{
    font-size:25px;
    height:25px;
    width:200px;
  }
  input.button{
    height:25px;
    width:50px;
  }
</style>
<form>
  <textarea >Value</textarea><input type='button' class='button' value='Go'>
</form>
```

Comment: make sure you don't have clear:left somewhere

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Have you tried playing with the vertical-align css property?

```
vertical-align:top;
```

That way everything will look consistent and you won't have to play with margins.

Answer (score 8):

```
textarea,input.button{display:inline-block;}
```

or

```
textarea,input.button{float:left;}
```

take your pick depending on which way your vertically challenged

Comment: thank you, but I can get them on the same line, it's just that when I do, they are in different places vertically. I tried both of those anyway and it made no difference.

Comment: which alignment do you want? top or flush bottom?

Comment: Also - make sure you have valid doctype and also make the form a block element as you'll get more reliable results.

Answer (score 3):

Adding a `vertical-align` seems to [work for me](http://jsfiddle.net/mXtvC/):

```
<style type='text/css'>
  form{display:inline;}
  textarea{width:200px;height:25px;font-size:25px;vertical-align:middle}
  input.button{width:50px;height:25px;vertical-align:middle}
</style>
<form><textarea >Value</textarea><input type='button' class='button' value='Go'></form>
```

Comment: @RyanStortz: Can't say for certain.  I'm on Firefox 8.0 here.  Seems to work in IE 9.0 as well.  (Though in the latter there are scroll buttons on the `textarea` which is ugly, you might want to explicitly remove those for browsers which add them by default.)

Comment: Yea, it's working for me. I have a simple js function that increases the height of the textarea for every line break so it's not a problem.

Comment: I had the same problem, and the vertical-align: top worked for me, except for the last element. I had a select, a div (created by the chosen jquery plugin), an input text and a input type=submit. The controls are all aligned, except for the button, wich is some pixels lower than the other controls.

Comment: Sorry, i discover my problem, it was another css class setting a margin-top: 10px. :(

Answer (score 2):

You can usually use `display:inline-block;` or `float:left;` Are you wanting items to be alighed at the top or bottom?

In your example you haven't closed the input type, it should be `type='button'` - you're missing an apos.

Answer (score 1):

Just give `float:left` to the textarea

http://jsfiddle.net/2qdJc/2/

Comment: I really have a thing against floats, they  just seem so random to me, but thanks I think I can get it to work now.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input /></td>
    <td><input /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Sure, it makes the CSS purists squirm, but it's certainly easy...

Comment: And the HTML purists, and the JavaScript purists, and web developers in general...

Comment: I like this idea, however I am trying to move away from tables for this page because of all the content being loaded.

Comment: @Ryan : I understand.  And I knew I'd get down votes.  But you did ask for simple and there's nothing easier than a simple table for aligning form inputs.  The first time you decide to nest a table, though, rethink the design.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this ( worked in my case ):

```
<div style="width:150px"><p>Start: <input  type="text" id="your_id"></p> 
  </div>

<div style="width:130px;margin-left: 160px;margin-top: -52px">
<a href="#" data-role="button" data-mini="true">Button</a>
</div>
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gn3qx6w6/1/

Comment: Simple and nice example. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For me i used a div and put all inputs in div and used vertical-align:top; for div

```
<div style="vertical-align:top">
        <span id="FromDate">From Date</span><input id="FromDatetext" style="margin-left:10px" type="text" name="startdate" />
        <span id="ToDate"> To Date</span><input id="ToFatetext" type="text" name="enddate" />
        <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-dark" />
    </div>
```