# Aligning 2 HTML inputs in the same line, when input[type=text] was already defined

Tags: html, css

I want to align two inputs in the same line.

I used the solutions available here:

http://jsfiddle.net/XAkXg/

http://www.java2s.com/Code/HTMLCSS/Form/inputclassidselectorandpropertyselector.htm

[Aligning html inputs on same line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8577123/aligning-html-inputs-on-same-line)

[html form - make inputs appear on the same line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18470682/html-form-make-inputs-appear-on-the-same-line/18470972)

Everything would work, but in my case, the `input[type=text]` has been defined earlier

The CSS code looks pretty much as this:

```
 input {
   margin-left: 50px;
   }
   input[type=text] {
   width: 75%;
   min-width: 450px;
   padding: 12px 20px;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   outline: none;
   border: 1px solid #f7fbff;
   background-color: #f7fbff;
   
    }
 
    input[type=text]:focus {
        background-color: #c6e2f2;
    }

    input[type=number]:focus {
        background-color: #c6e2f2;
    }
```

and now I have implemented the location feature into my HTML code:

```
                        <figure class="fig" id="location">
                                <label>
                                    <div class="order">1</div>
                                    <p>Location<span class="asterisk">&#42;</span></p>
                                </label>
                                <button class="locbtn" id="btn-geolocation">Find my location</button>
                                <br>
                                <label for="lat" class="location">Latitude</label>
                                <input type="text" name="latitude" class="location">
                                <label for="lon" class="location">Longitude</label>
                                <input type="text" name="longitude" class="location">
                                <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                            </figure>
```

and accordingly CSS:

```
.location {
 width: 50x;
 float: left;
 vertical-align: top;
 margin: auto;

  }

 .location input[type=text]{
  width: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
   }
```

and the effect is, as you can see below:

[image]

the input texts don't work, since they have been defined earlier in the code (for entire form).

How can I make the input[type=text] definition also for this section considered?

Moreover, instead of `display: inline-block`; I tried: `display: inline`; and `float: left`;   It didn't work either.

Comment: I took the html and css you provided and got a different result. I'm not seeing the same problem, so something is missing in your question. Also, I'm not sure what you mean by *aligning on the same line*. What does that mean? How? Please describe it in your question and don't link to other places unless you have to.

Comment: I used your HTML/CSS and Latitude&Longitude are aligned for me. Can you check once.

Comment: I sorted it. I am going to post the answer soon. Thanks.